# Does a minimized Remote Desktop session uses bandwith?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, bandwidth

I have a simple  question. Does a minimized Remote Desktop session uses bandwidth? I would like to have remote connections permanently up but I was wondering if this would increase the bandwidth consumption of my hosts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I know it should send keep-alive (or something like that) packets, so the connection does not end and it use very little band.
When it is minimized it does not use a lot of bandwidth.
Even when it is up and you are working it just refresh a block when it is changed.
Good Luck.

Comment: I forgot to mention that there will be activity on the connected hosts. I just don't want the updates if I'm not looking at them 'cos the remote session is minimized.

Comment: Logically the remote host sends the data because it doesn't know if you had minimized the remote Desktop.
But to be sure and see what is going on, Try using wireshark as Cipi said or in linux you can use tcpdump.

Comment: As the client knows the server can know. Anyway I'll try Cipi approach. Thanks.

Comment: I tried the scenario.
It uses bandwidth.
Good Luck

Comment: You're right. It still uses bandwidth. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like **NO**. How you can check it (how I checked it):

- Start Wireshark live capture on the network interface that you use to connect to the remote host
- Keep the remote session visible - you can see the packets arriving from the IP address of the remote host
- Minimize the remote session - you can't see anything coming from the remote host, or the traffic gets drastically reduced